# Cómo hacer para que un código Javascript no dependa de URLs externas

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome

Me encontré un Javascript que crea un botón, pero resulta que siempre llama o devuelve una llamada a una web externa, pero necesito que corra sin necesidad de que vaya o reciba esa llamada.

No sé cómo llamarlo, pero quisiera que funcione sin que acceda a esa web.

El código lo he subido a Mega porque es muy largo para pegarlo aquí. Lo he "modificado". Están comentadas las partes que deseo modificar:

- https://mega.nz/file/h4p3wYAK#Jm3tWuY9AYScNhLxB3SqCsOHoi6gZ3yVyTVze0UNPmY

Aquí está, igualmente, el código completo:

```js
giter1 = "1J4tdRXFxTy39EjeSYJR9vJX6hgTnrs2x"
giter2 = "u15i114O61"

chrome.storage.local.get(['pushpadmi'], function(result) {
 var litomo = result.pushpadmi
 if (typeof litomo === "string") {
  if (giter1 === litomo) {
   chrome.storage.local.get(['pushpadqu'], function(resultt) {
    var letomo = resultt.pushpadqu
    if (typeof letomo === "string") {
     if (giter2 === letomo) {
      if (document.getElementById('edit_profile_form_btc_address')+(1) !== 1) {
       var pbdocu = document.getElementById('edit_profile_form_btc_address').value;
       if (litomo === pbdocu) {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('bold withdraw_btc_address').length === 1) {
         pbdoco = document.getElementsByClassName('bold withdraw_btc_address')[0].textContent;
         if (pbdoco === litomo) {
          chrome.storage.local.get(['pushpadyu'], function(resulta) {
           var miflor = resulta.pushpadyu
           if (typeof miflor === "string") {
            albeni()
           }
          });
         }
        }
       }
      }
     } else {
      litomo = "";
      letomo = "";
      chrome.storage.local.clear();
      //console.log('La confisss no combinan...', 'se borrarán');
      yakui()
     }
    } else {
     litomo = "";
     letomo = "";
     yakui()
    }
   });
  } else {
   litomo = "";
   chrome.storage.local.clear();
   yakui()
  }
 } else {
  litomo = "";
  yakui()
 }
});

function yakui() {
 if (typeof sara === "undefined") {
  var scrupty = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(scrupty);
  scrupty.setAttribute('id', 'noactnpro');
  var scrupty = ""


  var scrupt = document.createElement("script");
  document.body.appendChild(scrupt);
  scrupt.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  scrupt.setAttribute('id', 'probano1');
  scrupt.setAttribute('async', '');
  scrupt.setAttribute('src', 'https://hostpollo.ddns.net/actnpro/datos/jsactpro/'+giter2+'.js');
 }
}



var intprosta = setInterval(function() {

 if (document.getElementById('actnpro1')+(1) !== 1) {
  bakoranosai1 = document.getElementById('actnpro1').textContent;
  if (typeof giter1 === "string") {
   if (typeof bakoranosai1 === "string") {
    if (bakoranosai1 === giter1) {
     //console.log ('si se cargó)
     proregitv1 = "yes"
    }
   }
  }
   var remopro1 = document.getElementById("actnpro1");
   document.body.removeChild(remopro1);

 }

 if (document.getElementById('actnpro2')+(1) !== 1) {
  if (typeof proregitv1 === "string") {
   bakoranosai2 = document.getElementById('actnpro2').textContent;
  if (typeof giter2 === "string") {
   if (typeof bakoranosai2 === "string") {
    if (bakoranosai2 === giter2) {
     //console.log ('si se cargó )
     proregitv2 = "yes"
    }
   }
  }
   var remopro2 = document.getElementById("actnpro2");
   document.body.removeChild(remopro2);

  }
 }

 if (typeof proregitv2 === "string") {
  var scrupt = document.createElement("script");
  document.body.appendChild(scrupt);
  scrupt.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  scrupt.setAttribute('id', 'probano2');
  scrupt.setAttribute('src', 'https://hostpollo.ddns.net/actnpro/datos/jsactpro/'+giter2+'.js?yactnpro3=yes');
  clearInterval(intprosta);
 }

}, 500);




var remopro3 = setInterval(function() {

 if (document.getElementById('probano2')+(1) !== 1) {
   var reprobano2 = document.getElementById("probano2");
   document.body.removeChild(reprobano2);
   actnproto = "yes";
   clearInterval(remopro3);
 }

},1000);




ctnproto=0;
var intctnproto = setInterval(function() {

 if (typeof actnproto === "string") {
  if (actnproto === "yes") {
   if (typeof localStorage.diu === "string") {
    actnproto = 0;
    var lilito = localStorage.diu
    if (document.getElementById('edit_profile_form_btc_address')+(1) !== 1) {
     var sanu = document.getElementById('edit_profile_form_btc_address').value;
     if (sanu === giter1) {
      if (document.getElementsByClassName('bold withdraw_btc_address').length === 1) {
      var cabe = document.getElementsByClassName('bold withdraw_btc_address')[0].textContent
       if (giter1 === cabe) {
        if (typeof localStorage.duo === "string") {
         if (typeof localStorage.dou === "string") {
          chrome.storage.local.set({pushpadmi: giter1}, function() {});
          chrome.storage.local.set({pushpadqu: giter2}, function() {});
          chrome.storage.local.set({pushpadyu: lilito}, function() {});
          //console.log('bien, se activó correctamente la extensión');
          yakomo()
          clearInterval(intctnproto);
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
},600);







function yakomo() {
 chrome.storage.local.get(['pushpadmi'], function(result) {
  var litomo = result.pushpadmi
  if (typeof litomo === "string") {
   if (giter1 === litomo) {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['pushpadqu'], function(resultt) {
     var letomo = resultt.pushpadqu
     if (typeof letomo === "string") {
      if (giter2 === letomo) {
       if (document.getElementById('edit_profile_form_btc_address')+(1) !== 1) {
        var pbdocu = document.getElementById('edit_profile_form_btc_address').value;
        if (litomo === pbdocu) {
         if (document.getElementsByClassName('bold withdraw_btc_address').length === 1) {
          pbdoco = document.getElementsByClassName('bold withdraw_btc_address')[0].textContent;
          if (pbdoco === litomo) {
           chrome.storage.local.get(['pushpadyu'], function(resulta) {
            var miflor = resulta.pushpadyu
            if (typeof miflor === "string") {
             albeni()
            }
           });
          }
         }
        }
       }
      } else {
       litomo = "";
       letomo = "";
       chrome.storage.local.clear();
       //console.log('La confisss no combinan...', 'se borrarán');
       //yakui()
      }
     } else {
      litomo = "";
      letomo = "";
      //yakui()
     }
    });
   } else {
    litomo = "";
    chrome.storage.local.clear();
    //yakui()
   }
  } else {
   litomo = "";
   //yakui()
  }
 });
}




////////////////PROBANDO CARGAR CONTENIDO A TRAVES DE VARIABLES, EN EL DOM   INCIO



//AREA DE PRUEBAS   FINAL





////////////////BOTON Copy Countdown     INICIO
//CREA EL BOTON Copy Countdown   INICIO

function merkalla() {

 if (typeof buylo !== "number") {

  if (document.getElementsByClassName("countdown_show2").length) {
 
   if (document.getElementById("d2fbcptime")+(1) === 1) {

    var d2fbcptime = document.createElement("button");
    document.body.appendChild(d2fbcptime);
    d2fbcptime.setAttribute("id", "d2fbcptime");
    d2fbcptime.setAttribute("style", "display:block; margin:auto;")
    document.getElementById("d2fbcptime").textContent="Copy Countdown";

    var chamon = document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(chamon);
    chamon.setAttribute("id", "chamon");

    evd2fbcptime()

    buylo = 0;
   }

  }
 }
}

//CREA EL BOTON Copy Countdown   FINAL



//CREA UN EVENTO DE ESCUCHA, PARA CUANDO SE HAGA CLICK EN EL BOTON Copy Countdown; SE LLAME A LA FUNCION: copyToClipboard    INICIO

function evd2fbcptime() {
 if (document.getElementById("d2fbcptime")+(1) !== 1){
 document.getElementById("d2fbcptime").addEventListener("click", copyToClipboard);
 clearInterval(evd2fbcptime);
 }
}

//CREA UN EVENTO DE ESCUCHA, PARA CUANDO SE HAGA CLICK EN EL BOTON Copy Countdown; SE LLAME A LA FUNCION: copyToClipboard    FINAL



//FUNCION QUE HACE LA MAGIA POSIBLE DE QUE COPIE AL CLIPBOARD, ENTRE OTRAS COSAS; COMO CREAR CUADRO DE DIALOGO PARA PONER LO COPIADO INICIO

 function copyToClipboard(){

  if (document.getElementById("chamon")+(1) !== 1) {
   var elementta = document.getElementById("chamon");
   elementta.parentNode.removeChild(elementta);
  } 
     
  if (document.getElementById("dummy_id")+(1) !== 1) {
   var element = document.getElementById("dummy_id");
   element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  }

  if (document.getElementById("chaman")+(1) !== 1) {
   var elementt = document.getElementById("chaman");
   elementt.parentNode.removeChild(elementt);
  }

  if (document.getElementsByClassName("countdown_show2").length) {
  var yola = document.getElementsByClassName("countdown_show2")[0].textContent;
  
  var dummy = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.appendChild(dummy);
  dummy.setAttribute("id", "dummy_id");
  dummy.setAttribute("style", "display:block; margin:auto; text-align:center;")
  document.getElementById("dummy_id").value=yola;
  dummy.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");

  var chaman = document.createElement("br");
  document.body.appendChild(chaman);
  chaman.setAttribute("id", "chaman");

  } else {

 if (document.getElementById("d2fbcptime")+(1) !== 1) {
  var compbtntmctn = document.getElementById("d2fbcptime");
  document.body.removeChild(compbtntmctn);
 }
      
  }
                      };

//COMO CREAR CUADRO DE DIALOGO PARA PONER LO COPIADO FINAL
////////////////BOTON Copy Countdown     FINAL



//INTERVALO INICIADOR DEL CREADOR DEL BOTON COPY COUNTDOWN... SI TODO ESTA EN ORDEN, LLAMA LA CREADOR DEL BOTON COPY COUNTDOWN     INICIO

var comandos80 = setInterval(function(){

 if (typeof sara !== "undefined") {
  chrome.storage.local.get(['pushpadyu'], function(result) {
   var lelos=result.pushpadyu;
   var distor=100
   var distar=86
   var dilan=3+4
   var dailon=dilan*3
   var escaramusa=1
   if (sara === sessionStorage.diu&&sara === localStorage.diu&&sara.length-distor <= localStorage.diu.length&&sara.length+distor >= sessionStorage.diu.length&&lelos === sara&&lelos.length-distor === localStorage.diu.length-distor&&lelos.length === sessionStorage.diu.length&&sara === lelos&&lelos.length-distor <= sara.length&&sara.length-distar <= lelos.length&&dilan-1+1*1+2-2*2/2+6+1/2*1 >= dilan&&dailon+distor === lelos.length&&dailon+escaramusa^3 <= dailon+distar&&lelos.length-dailon === distor+5+3-8) {
    //console.log('escaramusapecabien')
    bwya();
    blkads();
    merkalla();
   }
  })
 }
}, 300);
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente **nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Necesitamos algo más de explicación de qué estás haciendo: ¿es una extensión de chrome? ¿puedes compartir el archivo de manifiesto? Además, ¿sabías que con el operador `&&` te puedes ahorrar tantos `if` anidados?

Comment: @OscarGarcia Amigo es un botón que encontré la verdad estoy tratando de quitarle la dependencia de usar giter1 , giter2 y el manifiesto en que influye al programa osea si tiene manifiesto pero no entiendo porque la necesidad de adjuntarlo

Comment: Ahh, vale, ahora entiendo lo de que "no dependa de una web específica". No te refieres a que solo funcione en un dominio dado, si no que no cargue ese javascript de esos dominios. En principio esos javascripts imagino que serán los que generan esos botones. Si no quieres que carguen de esa página tendrás que obtener los javascripts, modificarlos a tu dominio, y enlazarlos en la extensión. Comparte la URL de la extensión (lo que tú llamas "botón"). Otra cosa que no entiendo es cuando dices que "este código se ejecuta acciones atraves de un .bat". ¿A que'te refieres con eso?

Comment: no quiero que dependan de una web especifica solo quiero que corra en mi pc.! osea no estoy interesado en hacer algo macro solo algo funcional.! bueno el programa hace un botón por lo que tengo entendido y las función del botón es activar el bat

Comment: es obligatorio que esta clase de extensiones se dirigan a una url para pedir permisos o algo asi disculpa la novatada!

Comment: Dame al menos el enlace de la extensión porque ahora mismo estoy muy perdido con lo que quieres hacer. Tú quizá lo tengas muy claro en tu mente, pero ten en cuenta que nosotros no tenemos ni idea de para qué quieres usarlo ni de qué "botón" estás hablando hasta que lo veamos y lo entendamos.

Comment: bueno me la pasaron a mi no esta en ninguna web, no lo pude adjuntar completo es muy grande el script

Comment: A mi parecer tienes dos opciones (ordenadas de menor a mayor dificultad): 1.- Incluir el contenido del script en base64 en el atributo `src` como [datos URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Datos_URIs). 2.- Incluir el contenido del javascript al final de tu script, comprobando que no entre en conflicto con otro código que tengas en él.

Comment: osea como esto impide que giter1 , giter2 y if (typeof proregitv2 === "string")
que no dependa de estas variables

Comment: Obtén su valor con un `console.log(giter2);` justo antes de que se use para conocer su valor y poder usarlo directamente.

Comment: He añadido el script como me sugirio espero me ayude

Comment: Perdona que haya tardado en ver tus comentarios Omar. Como eres el autor de la pregunta a ti siempre te llegará una notificación cuando alguien te deje un mensaje, pero al resto de usuarios solo nos llega la notificación si nos nombras poniendo un  @ delante de nuestro nombre.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código sin modificar? El que has compartido da error, encuentra un `else` inesperado.

Comment: Osea el documento original de los if como al principio si si puedo y también puedo añadirle el .json  si es de mejor ayuda @OscarGarcia

Comment: Si el complemento es público, un enlace a su página oficial o de descarga también iría bien, para probar su funcionamiento tras modificarlo. Con solo una parte del código no se puede hacer mucho más que darte una guía.

Comment: no viene de enlace directo la persona me contacto privado y no existe pagina oficial como dice la original es un archivo me lo enviaron telegram el cual viene con un activador para un .bat que también el me proporciono dicho proveedor@OscarGarcia

Answer (score 1):

El código está ofuscado para dificultarte la obtención de los scripts externos, pero se pueden obtener y sustituir fácilmente siguiendo las siguientes instrucciones:

**Obtención de las URLs de los scripts**

Deberás obtener las URLs modificando el código para hacer un seguimiento de las URLs cargadas usando, por ejemplo, `console.log()` de la siguiente manera:

```
  var scrupt = document.createElement("script");
  document.body.appendChild(scrupt);
  scrupt.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  scrupt.setAttribute('id', 'probano1');
  scrupt.setAttribute('async', '');
  scrupt.setAttribute('src', 'https://hostpollo.ddns.net/actnpro/datos/jsactpro/'+giter2+'.js');
  /* URL Nº1 */
  console.log("URL Nº1", 'https://hostpollo.ddns.net/actnpro/datos/jsactpro/'+giter2+'.js');
```

En la consola de depuración te irán apareciendo cada una de las URLs (deberás marcarlas con un comentario para recordar posteriormente a qué parte del código pertenece cada URL que aparezca en la consola de depuración) que deberás convertir a [datos URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Datos_URIs).

**Conversión a datos URI**

Puedes descargar el archivo javascript y pasarlo por el siguiente conversor en línea:

- https://www.site24x7.com/es/tools/imagen-a-datos-uri.html

Aunque el selector de archivos solo muestre imágenes, puedes marcar *Todos los archivos (*.*)* en el menú desplegable para que te aparezca también tu código javascript, generando una salida parecida a ésta (aunque muuuuuucho más larga):

```
data:text/javascript;base64,77u/Y29uc29sZS5sb2coIkVsIGNvbnZlcnNvciBkZSBqYXZhc2NyaXB0IGEgZGF0b3MgVVJJIGZ1bmNpb25hIGNvcnJlY3RhbWVudGUiKTs=
```

Con lo que podrías sustituir las líneas anteriores por:

```js
var scrupt = document.createElement("script");
document.body.appendChild(scrupt);
scrupt.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
scrupt.setAttribute('id', 'probano1');
scrupt.setAttribute('async', '');
scrupt.setAttribute('src', 'data:text/javascript;base64,77u/Y29uc29sZS5sb2coIkVsIGNvbnZlcnNvciBkZSBqYXZhc2NyaXB0IGEgZGF0b3MgVVJJIGZ1bmNpb25hIGNvcnJlY3RhbWVudGUiKTs=');
```

En este ejemplo podrás ver cómo se genera un mensaje en la consola de depuración que pone el siguiente texto:

> El conversor de javascript a datos URI funciona correctamente

Indicando que la conversión ha sido satisfactoria.

Realizando esta sustitución podrás sustituir las cargas externas por datos URI y así evitar llamadas al servidor externo, pero eso no quita que alguno de esos códigos javascripts carguen a su vez un recurso externo fuera de tu control.

Answer (score 1):

HISTORIA:
Ese código era parte de una extensión para Google Chrome de nombre: "NPROTOFREEBTC" . Fue creada para funcionar en la faucet: "FREEBTC" . Ayudaba a reclamar una recompensa gratuito de btc cada hora. Se combinaba con otra extensión de nombre: "BUSTER" , se combinaba con un programa para Windows de nombre: "Mouse and Keyboard Recorder" y se combinaba con una herramienta batch en windows. Se iniciaba la herramienta batch; esta era la encargada de ejecutar: "NPROTOFREEBTC" y tratar su resultado.

El resultado de la extensión: "NPROTOFREEBTC" ; en conjunto con lo antes mencionado, era guardado en el clipboard. Luego en windows, se utilizaba powershell para obtener dicho resultado copiado y después finalmente era pasado a la herramienta batch, que se encargaba de filtrar si los datos obtenidos eran un countdown o cuenta regresiva válida en este formato: "59m:58s" . Si no era válido se ejecutaba otra vez, si era válido se cargaba en una función interna o reloj; hasta contar todos los segundos entregados en el countdown. "[Video NPROTOFREEBTC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrYrpe-2rNo)"

Básicamente eso era: "NPROTOFREEBTC" ...

RESPUESTA:
Soy quien desarrolló NPROTOFREEBTC y soy quien te pasó la extensión vía telegram. Cometí un error y te la pasé sin haberla ofuscado completamente; cuando me di cuenta fue demasiado tarde. Pero luego como se me coló sin ofuscar bien; actualicé el código y desautoricé la versión antigua en el servidor. Si hubieras logrado desofuscar el código y entender bien todo lo que hacía y hubieras retirado la parte que vigila alteraciones en la configuración de activación, igual nunca te iba a funcionar por dicha desautorización. Y también, nunca te iba a funcionar sin las 3 llaves de activación en mi servidor; la cual a su vez eran únicas igual que cada extensión entregada vía telegram. Y finalmente, tampoco te iba a funcionar sin las funciones más importantes que completaban la extensión; las cuales se obtenían luego de haber pasado el proceso previo de activación de 3 llaves únicas y de un solo uso en mi servidor.

Al final lo que tenías en las manos era un cascarón vacío con solo algunos pasos de seguridad y peticiones de una sola vez de la verdadera extensión ofuscada descargada desde mi servidor. Y para finalizar, todo esto sin contarte sobre la seguridad anti genios que tenía el batch para prevenir modificaciones a todo el conjunto de herramientas NPROTOFREEBTC. FIN

Gracias por el apoyo.
Atentamente: FvUshyonFly

Comment: Pero esto no es una respuesta, jajajajajaja

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer].

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover es una respuesta completa sobre lo que estaba intentando hacer Omar. Quería burlar la seguridad de activación controlada por un servidor externo de mi propiedad. 

Si lees y analizas todo a profundidad; es una respuesta a lo que él intentaba hacer... Su pregunta está mal elaborada o enmascarada, y muy difícil iba a encontrar una respuesta tan completa a sus dudas como la del creador de la extensión.

Pero tienes razón "no es una respuesta que responde la pregunta" , pero responde más allá de ella. "Lo que intentó preguntar él"

Comment: @Jorgesys Muchas gracias ^_^

Comment: Parece mentira lol. Es una pena que te hayas enterado 3 años más tarde. Seguramente ya ni se acuerde de que hizo esta pregunta.

Comment: @Mateo Me di cuenta hace años, pero en ese momento no deseaba responder. Al buscar en google sobre mi sitio, la pregunta hecha sale... Lo más seguro es así; posiblemente ya ni se acuerde.